# UPDATING a column to take first letter from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to UPDATE my table to replace / insert in the INITIALS column, the first letter in the first name column

Table name: Mano

```
     Title  Firstname    Lastname    Telephone  Initial  Gender   More columns 
1    Mr     Adam             Smith         001    
2    Mrs    Angela           Evans         002       AE
3    Mr     Bill             Towny         003    
4    Miss   Dame             Beaut         004
```

I am interested in transforming it as per below

```
     Title  Firstname    Lastname    Telephone  Inital  Gender   More columns 
1    Mr     Adam             Smith         001      A
2    Mrs    Angela           Evans         002      A
3    Mr     Bill             Towny         003      B
4    Miss   Dame             Beaut         004      D
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a simple `update`:

```
update t
    set initials = left(firstname, 1);
```

I should point out that you don't even need a column.  You can declare this as a computed column:

```
alter t add initials as (left(firstname, 1));
```

This would provide a column called `initials` (assuming that name is not already used) that always has the first letter of the `firstname` column -- without an update.

Answer (score 2):

You can use substring function,

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Firstname, 1, 1) from mango;
```

Hope using this select statement you can update the table.

If you need the update query, let me know will give you

Answer (score 1):

Left is the best and would more better if we use this with TRIM to prevent the extra spaces if any:

```
UPDATE TABLE table1 SET Initial = LEFT(LTRIM(Firstname), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a computed column, will never be inconsistent:

```
alter table Mano add Initial as SUBSTR(Firstname, 1, 1)
```